# Is it possible to boot Ubuntu in UEFI shell to fix BIOS boot options?

Tags: uefi

Is there a possibility to boot to a UEFI shell using Ubuntu and fix my boot options?

I want to bring back the USB and HDD boot options. Right now, I have only 3: Windows Boot Manager, DVD drive, and PXE LAN.

I accidentally deleted these options through Clover Bootloader by clicking the option remove all Clover entries.

I was toying around with the `bcfg` command as advised by [this thread](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/guide-remove-extra-clover-bios-boot-entries-prevent-further-problems.175274/), but then I'd foolishly deleted them all.

I've installed Windows UEFI through LAN with SERVA, but it can't boot by itself even if I choose the Windows Boot Manager and disable the CSM option. I've also tried WinToUSB without success.

My plan is to boot Ubuntu by LAN PXE through SERVA, so can someone guide me how to do this? Is it possible to have a shell and fix BIOS?

I don't know if booting Clover is possible, nor if it is possible on SERVA.

Please help me to bring back those boot options.

Lastly, I also tried a Win DVD, but it doesn't boot.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly boot into the UEFI shell "also" with **Serva**.

http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html

*5.9 UEFI Shell*

Note: Please consider not all the Shell.efi available out there will be compatible with your UEFI firmware version.